# Storing python dates in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

is not there any way to store python dates or pyqt4 dates (QDate) in sqlite3 ? I'd not like to use sqlite's date types since i'll need to find the difference between dates that i'll store.That's what i'm trying :

```
    record = QtCore.QDate.currentDate()
    latest = self.calendar.selectedDate()

    db = sql.connect(":memory:")
    cur = self.db.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE  invoices(record, latest)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO invoices VALUES (?, ?)", (record, latest)) 
    db.commit()
```

That's the error : sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always pickle your object and store it as BLOB in your DB, although that might be overkill depending on your needs... http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Convert it to a timestamp first.

Comment: Or use adapters and converters or, I don't know QT and how it interacts with python types, use the `datetime` module: http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#default-adapters-and-converters

Comment: I tried storing it as timestamp but it also did not work but that link will solve it, i guess, thanks.http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#default-adapters-and-converters

Answer (score 0):

I tried many methods and most straightforward is convert it to timestamp, then when retrieve it back convert from timestamp to date and that's best solution because if you store it like string object it will be impossible to do logic operations on your data but with timestamp its simple...